# passing xml document to c# from php

Tags: c#, php

I need to pass the following xml document to my c# dll from PHP .Also i only need to pass the element watchlists and its child element.Its a DOMDocument

```
<assumption_list>
<assumption name="test" id="23" description="test1" is_shared="no">
<watchlists>
<watchlist globalissuer="k" prepayrate="" prepaytype="CPR" defaultrate="" defaulttype="CDR" lossrate="" lagmonths=""/>
</watchlists>
</assumption>
</assumption_list>
```

1:Should i convert this xml document to string and then pass it to c# dll,if yes should is there any PHP function that does that like xmldoc.tostring() of c#

2:How do i grab the watchlists element from this xml document.i tried using this code.

```
$watchlists = $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('watchlists');
```

If this is the right way then how do i pass this node to c# ,should i convert it to string  or just pass this xml node directly.

Any feedback would be really helpfull.

Comment: yes it is a simplexmldocument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think there is a `SimpleXML::getElementsByTagName()`

This should echo what you want:

```
$result = $xml->xpath('/assumption_list/assumption/watchlists');
foreach($result as $node)
    echo $node->asXML();
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/y2DW5gN1)

---

**EDIT :**

You edited your question and changed SimpleXML into DOMDocument

```
$result = $dom->getElementsByTagName('watchlists');
foreach($result as $element)
    echo $dom->saveXML($element);
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/yva9KYa6)

Comment: i need to pass a string representing the actual xml with all tags .asXml only gives element value and ignores the element

Comment: @user3290807 That is not true. You are probably viewing it in a browser. In the browser you need to do "View Source"

Comment: Hi It seems i have a DOMDocument rather than SimpleXml,is there a way to get the same output or is there way to convert the DOMDocument to SimpleXml.